# Blazemeter only using even records in csv data config

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I'm using Blazemeter to run my JMeter test scripts to load test it. I've uploaded the jmx file and a csv for the multiple user logins but it only uses those records on even numbered lines lines of the csv. Here is the csv:

```
60001,TestPass123!
60002,TestPass123!
60003,TestPass123!
60004,TestPass123!
60005,TestPass123!
60006,TestPass123!
60007,TestPass123!
60008,TestPass123!
60009,TestPass123!
60010,TestPass123!
```

CSV Data Config settings:

```
File Encoding :  (blank)
Variable names : login,password
Delimiter :      ,
Allow quoted data? :  False
Recycle on EOF:       True
Stop thread on EOF? : False
```

Thread Group Settings (from jmx file):

```
Number of threads (users) : 1
Ramp up period (secs) : 1
Loop Count : 1
```

Blazemeter Settings:

```
Engine(s):Console Only
Server(s):1
JMeter Version:2.11
Thread(s) per engine:10
Rampup:202
Iterations:1
Duration:10m
```

When I check my results, I only get entries for firms ending in even numbers. Does look like  a config setting or a timing issue? When I use the same script file with mulitple logins as above locally, it works fine. When I use the same script with a logins csv that has one entry in it in Blazemeter, it runs fine.

Why is Blazemeter (or JMeter) only picking up alternating records in the csv file?

Comment: I originally had the CSV Config outside of the thread group. I moved it inside the thread group and it's fine. If anyone can offer a reason why this is the case, I'd appreciate it but it's solved as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you (I work for BlazeMeter). On a side note, I suggest debugging on your local machine by running the script inside of JMeter and if it's good then uploading to BlazeMeter. It's much easier to see the actual calls in JMeter with the tree listener.

Comment: Hi there, I do check them out in JMeter locally first before testing in my dev account on BM before moving the tests to the Production account to the larger number of users testing. I think it's to do with JMeter and how it handles the hierarchy of config vs thread loops. Thanks for your reply, it's good to know you guys are around on here too.